# Subtle Java Regular Expressions

Tags: java, regex

```
String str = "1234545";
String regex = "\\d*";

Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m1 = p1.matcher(str);

while (m1.find()) {

    System.out.print(m1.group() + " found at index : ");
    System.out.print(m1.start());

}
```

The output of this program is `1234545 found at index:0 found at index:7`.

My question is:
why is there a space printed when actually there is no space in the `str`.

Comment: `\\d*` matches an empty string which is at the end of your string. Perhaps you intended `\\d+`

Comment: space printed where?

Comment: It didn't print a space, it printed an empty string. The two are not the same thing.

Comment: @Jonk , can u plz explain.

Comment: @Jonk, I mean where is that empty string in str.

Comment: `""` is an empty string (i.e. a string containing **nothing at all**), `" "` is a space.

Comment: @Aamir the output doesn't bear any relationship to the code anywhere. Where is 'found' coming from? and, where does the space after ':' come from?

Comment: @Jonk, but " " is not empty here , it is containg characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space printed between `"index:0"` and `"at index:7"` is coming from the string literal that you print. It was supposed to come after the matched string; however, in this case the match is empty.

Here is what's going on: the first match consumes all digits in the string, leaving zero characters for the following match. However, the following match succeeds, because the asterisk `*` in your expression allows matching empty strings.

To avoid this confusion in the future, add delimiter characters around the actual match, like this:

```
System.out.print("'" + m1.group() + "' at index : ");
```

Now you would see an empty pair of single quotes, showing that the match was empty.